# Elements outside document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I was just reading this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) by MDN and saw that, according to the specifications for "document.getElementById", **elements not in the document** are not searched.

I'm confused by why/how elements can be outside the document. How does this differ from the definition of an absolutely positioned element (namely, that absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow). I'm not entirely sure the absolutely positioned element case applies to this, but a clarification on what it means to be "outside the document" and why something like that would be used would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A document is a tree, but you can have nodes (leaves/branches) that aren't on the tree (either because they never were, or because they've come off it).

Examples will probably make this clearer.

Example 1: Never in the tree:

Here's an element that's not in any document:

```
var elm = document.createElement('div');
elm.id = "foo";
```

That's an element, with an `id`, but it isn't part of any document.

Example 2: Removed from the tree:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="foo"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
// The div is in the document, so this works:
var elm = document.getElementById("foo");

// Now we remove it:
elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);

// 'elm' is no longer in any document
console.log(document.getElementById("foo")); // null
```

[Example 2 Live](http://jsbin.com/pehoc/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/pehoc/1/edit)

Comment: You might want to add an `id` to the loose element, as the question is especially about `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

*"not in the document"* means *"not stored in the DOM tree of the current document"*, i.e. the nodes exist in memory, but they're not "attached" to any node on the page.

A *corrollary* of that is that the elements must therefore be invisible, but it's for an entirely different reason to that of absolute position.  In the latter, the nodes do exist in the DOM, they just may not be position "on screen".